# count characters based on the order they appear

Tags: r

How does one count the characters based on the order they appear in a single length string. Below is an minimal example:

```
x <- "abbccdddaab"
```

First thought was this but it only counts them irrespective of order:

```
table(unlist(strsplit(x, "\\b")))

a b c d 
3 3 2 3
```

But the desired output is:

```
a b c d a b
1 2 2 3 2 1
```

I would imagine the solution would require a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rle` instead of `table` as `rle` returns the output as a `list` of `values` and `lengths` based on checking whether the adjacent elements are same or not

```
out <- rle(strsplit(x, "\\b")[[1]])
setNames(out$lengths, out$values)
# a b c d a b 
# 1 2 2 3 2 1
```

Comment: this is great, was not aware of `rle()` thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table::rleid` :

```
x <- "abbccdddaab"
tmp <- strsplit(x, "\\b")[[1]]
table(data.table::rleid(tmp))

#1 2 3 4 5 6 
#1 2 2 3 2 1
```

Comment: thanks for this, good to know there is also a `data.table` solution